# Pro foam gun leaks at can adapter

Tags: spray-foam

[image: professional spray foam gun leaking at adapter]

The can appears to be seated correctly and screwed in firmly. And yet it is leaking foam around the adapter - I saw it starting to slowly ooze out along the mating surface immediately after screwing in the can.

Is this a problem with the gun, or the can, or both? I've already flushed out the gun with the special can of solvent, and the gun dispenses freely.

For reference, this is the Great Stuff Pro 14 model gun. I've tried a cheaper model of spray foam gun in the past, and had this same problem but even worse. The can refused to seat correctly at all, and blew foam all over my floor before I could get to a trash can. I haven't seen anyone mention this issue anywhere else, which makes me wonder if I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: I had the same issue when I initially tried a cheap knock-off gun. Then "upgraded" to the same name-brand one you have and had much better luck. If you clean the foam off can you tell if it's leaking from between the can and the gun, or if it's leaking from where the can adapter part attaches to the rest of the gun?

Comment: @brhans It looks like it's between the can (which has its own built-in plastic connector) and the adapter which attaches to the rest of the gun. I can try taking it apart and getting a better photo before the foam fills the adapter completely.

Comment: The stub on the gun has to be completely clean, and solvent won't clean dried foam. But don't scratch the stub when scraping off dried foam (use a plastic tool like the edge of an old credit card.) The "cheaper gun" issue sounds like a potential cross-threading of the can to adapter from miles away and not seeing it.